# ActiveRecord Generate Condition SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, arel

My goal in writing a function is to allow callers to pass in the same condition arguments they would to a `where` call in ActiveRecord, and I want the corresponding Rails-generated SQL.

## Example

If my function receives a hash like this as an argument

```
role: 'Admin', id: [4, 8, 15]
```

I would expect to generate this string

```
"users"."role" = 'Admin' AND "users"."id" IN (4, 8, 15)
```

## Possible Solutions

I get the closest with `to_sql`.

```
pry(main)> User.where(role: 'Admin', id: [4, 8, 15])
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"role\" = 'Admin' AND \"users\".\"id\" IN (4, 8, 15)"
```

It returns almost exactly what I want; however, I would be more comfortable not stripping away the `SELECT ... WHERE` myself in case something changes in the way the SQL is generated. I realize the WHERE should always be there to split on, but I'd prefer an even less brittle approach.

My next approach was using Arel's `where_sql` function.

```
pry(main)> User.where(role: 'Admin', id: [4, 8, 15]).arel.where_sql
=> "WHERE \"users\".\"role\" = $1 AND \"users\".\"id\" IN (4, 8, 15)"
```

It gets rid of the `SELECT` but leaves the `WHERE`. I would prefer it to the above if it had already injected the sanitized role, but that renders it quite a bit less desirable.

I've also considered generating the SQL myself, but I would prefer to avoid that.

Do any of you know if there's some method right under my nose I just haven't found yet? Or is there a better way of doing this altogether?

```
Ruby  2.3.7
Rails 5.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I too would like to know how to get the conditions without the leading `WHERE`. I see in https://coderwall.com/p/lsdnsw/chain-rails-scopes-with-or that they used string manipulation to get rid of the `WHERE`, which seems messy but maybe the only solution currently. :/

`scope.arel.where_sql.gsub(/\AWHERE /i, "")`